# Stop MStest on first failure when running test container *.dll file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, mstest, msbuild-task

I am executing a test file from command line,

```
 mstest /testcontainer:test1.dll
```

This dll file contains multiple tests, is there a way i can stop the test on first test failure

**Note** - Can't change the code as the project files are too large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this StackOverflow post will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42168128/981727).

It describes creating a base class your unit test classes derive from. When a certain number of tests have failed, it will find the current process and kill it.

Comment: Is there any configuration changes that i can do.. Sorry but code is too big to make a change, please let me know if i can do any configuration changes into it..!!

Comment: @Mukul As far as I know, there isn't the configuration that could meet your requirement.

Comment: Thanks I tried with the same approach and that worked for me..!!